# click() function does not on any browser console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console.log

When I open a website on the browser. Now I want to click button through javascript console which every browser has. The button have class and the website is not using jquery so the code will be pure javascript.

> document.getElementsByClassName('btn-orange').trigger('click');
>   document.getElementsByClassName('btn-orange').click();

Thank you for taking time for helping me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('btn-orange')` returns an array of elements.

Comment: What are you asking? This question is really difficult to understand. Can you try to make it easier to read? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-orange')[0].click();
```

> This will work, because
>   **document.getElementsByClassName('btn-orange')** will give u an array of selected DOM elements, even if u have only one element with this
>   classname, it will be on position first of the array, and then u call
>   call click event on that element.